# Alternative for url parameter in ajax when publish

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using a WEB API controller in my application, and I am using ajax to call that controller method.

The url is:

```
url: "/api/Informations/" + link.attr("data-id")
```

This works perfectly on my local machine.

The problem is when I publish.

I have to change the URL to:

```
url: "ProjectNameOnServer/api/Informations/" + link.attr("data-id")
```

Is there a workaround for this?  Because if ever there were to be an issue concerning this, I would have to continuously change the url to test it on my local machine.. then when the issue is resolved.. change it back to the version where it works on the server.

Any ideas on this?

**UPDATE**

Route for api :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You can create constant in config file where dev and live server settings will be different.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't know how to do in asp.net, but like this one: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9/suggestions-for-settings-php-local-dev-development-server-live-server, where settings.php or config.php have all dev and live server settings. You can also add this file in ignore (like gitignore) list to not send settings on live server accidentally.

Comment: P.S. To answer your question - presumably the "api" route is one level below where your app is deployed? If so you should be able to use a relative path like `url: "api/Informations/" + link.attr("data-id")`. Note the lack of leading `/`. This should make the application self-contained, and agnostic about where it's deployed in the webserver's folder hierarchy.

Comment: When you use EF.. it pluralizes your models for controllers.. hence Informations.. additionally that's not the real name of my controller.. simply a test case

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid ok well fair enough, I didn't know. Did removing the `/` from the front of the URL help at all?

Comment: @ADyson it did not

Comment: How do you have the API Controller routes set up? If you share that code, it might provide some insight.

Comment: @krillgar sorry found it, see update

Comment: Is the ajax call in a .js file or on a cshtml page?

Comment: @RossBush cshtml page

Comment: You can save baseUrl in script file include into  to your all views. Only one time you need change url.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()` configuration, I would instead use Attribute Routing. Unfortunately, making this change can be time consuming, but it should solve your problems. (As a test, you could just set up a single action with attributes and see if it works.)

**Step 1** Replace the `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()` in your `WebApiConfig.Register` method with this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

**Step 2** Decorate your `InformationController` with the following attribute:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/information")]
public class InformationController: ApiController { ... }
```

**Step 3** Decorate your action with the following attribute(s):

```
[HttpPost, Route("{id:int}", Name = "InformationSingleGet"]
public Information Get([FromBody] int id) { ... }
```

**Step 4** Pass your route into your JavaScript using the Razor [UrlHelper.RouteUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl%28System.String%29) method:

```
var infoGetUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("InformationSingleGet")';
```

The benefit of using the `RouteUrl` method is that it will build out the URL for you without you having to change this between environments. Being able to reference them by name makes this very easy to find the right one.

One other thing, if you're not aware of is the [`FromUri`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.fromuriattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and [`FromBody`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attributes for telling your method where the action parameter is coming from.

Naturally if you're going to be using this in your production code, you should set up a Constants class where you set those route names in just a single place, and set them via reference to the properties. You also shouldn't be tossing variables into the JavaScript window object, but that's a different discussion.

**UPDATE**

If you're using the Route Engine like this, for any POSTs or other dynamic trailing pieces of the URL, you should instead use query string parameters as opposed to being a direct piece of the URL.

What happens whn you call `Url.RouteUrl` is that it will build out the entire URL at that point. So you need to know what any dynamic value that is a part of the URL is when you create the URL. This would be good if it is on the page for this (`api/information/1/details`), but if you're picking one from a list, you don't know that ahead of time. Therefore, query string parameters, or Body are the way to go.

In order to set up one with the dynamic parameters, you would have it set up like this:

```
[Route("{id:int}/details", Name = "InformationDetails")]
```

Then create it in your page like this:

```
var detailsUrl = '@Url.RouteUrl("InformationDetails", {id = model.Id})';
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include in the question that the method is `POST`, so should there be an edit done for Step 3?

Comment: Ah, yeah. I'll change that.

Comment: Sounds interesting, and how to tell which environment is current environment? Will it be possible to run app on local PC built in Release mode? If so, how?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov It shouldn't need to know which environment it is in. Setting up any sort of prefix is handled earlier in the URL before the relative path this generates gets created.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I just realized something with using this for POST. You should have the dynamic id as part of the request body instead of the URL. I'll expand in my answer.

Comment: I just tested this locally and when published and it works!

Comment: So it means that application knows that it is hosted in virtual folder on IIS and generates URL appropriately. That's even better.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Glad to hear it! Let the system do all that heavy lifting for you. Since you'll probably be going and redoing all your other routes, do check out my update on the dynamic URL parameters, and when to use Body data instead of as part of the URL.

Comment: I am actually testing my Delete actions now.. and am experiencing issues.. I am looking into it

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid Make sure you have your verbs set everywhere, and be wary of the "gotcha" in my update when generating that dynamic URL.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I don't see your result in your update. You have the correct HTTP Verb set in your AJAX call? Check if the URL that gets generated has the `/` before your ID.

Comment: In my update 2, I gave the url that is being seen.. for some reason I am getting the projectname when running locally.. but when I do the HttpPost for creating I don't see the projectname in the url..

Comment: Hold on.. stupid mistake.. I was on the wrong page.. omg.. need coffee

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143101/discussion-between-bville-kid-and-krillgar).

Answer (score 1):

In your master page or in a JavaScript file that is inlcuded in the master page, create a variable and set the base URL in it. and for all ajax operations append this variable  before the URL.

So, if you are using MVC for your UI, you can do the following inside your _layouts.cshtml.

```
<script>
var settings = {};
settings.baseUri = '@Request.ApplicationPath';
</script>
```

And in your ajax call, you can change it to be:

```
url: settings.baseUri + "/api/Informations/" + link.attr("data-id")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below function in my js file to access api:

```
var isAppFolder = true;//true: when deployed & false: when running locally
function rootUrl() {
if (!window.location.origin) {
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');
}
var url = window.location.origin + "/";

if (isAppFolder != true)
    return url;

var url = url + location.pathname.split('/')[1] + '/';
if (isAppFolder == true)
    return url;

var url = url + location.pathname.split('/')[2] + '/';

return url;
}
```

and access url like this:

```
url: rootUrl() +"api/Informations/" + link.attr("data-id")
```

Hope this helps.